# Proving that a secant line has points inside and outside of the circle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose that the line l is a secant line of the circle C(O, r). Let P1 and P2 be the two points of intersection between l and C(O, r). Use geometry (and not analysis) to prove
that if P1 − Q − P2 holds then Q is in the interior of C(O, r). Also, prove that if P1 − P2 − Q holds then Q is in the exterior of C(O, r).

I have no idea where to start on this one. I feel like I've tried every approach. Please, any tips or advice would be helpful.

Edit:

1. The *interior* of C(O, r) is the set of points {P ∈ U : OP < r}.
2. The *exterior* of C(O, r) is the set of points {P ∈ U : OP > r}.
3. The *circle* with center O and radius r (notation: C(O, r)) is the set of points C(O, r) = {P ∈ U : OP = r}

Just help on the first question would be great. I just don't know where to start.

Comment: Every approach? Edit your post to show us. Also, include your course’s definition of interior and exterior of the circle.

Comment: added the definitions.

Comment: You just need this theorem: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI19.html

Answer (score 1):

How acceptable is this:

If P1 − Q − P2 holds
then Q is closer to the center
than P1 and P2 and is thus in the interior.

If P1-P2-Q holds then
Q is further from the center
than P2 and is
thus in the exterior.

Not sure how you define
interior and exterior
other than distance from center.

I think those statements about P1, P2, and Q
can be proved by
analytic geometry
combined with
Q = tP1+(1-t)P2
with 0 < t < 1 for between and interior
and
t < 0 or t > 1 for not between and exterior.